# How to override Allauth login template in app in Django?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I tried overriding Django Allauth login templates in my app, but it didn't work.
`APP_DIRS` in `settings.py` is also True.

**Login template location:**

```
ProjectName\main\templates\main\account\login.html
```

Any idea how to fix this, without creating a `templates` folder on project level?

Comment: What is the extra `main` directory for? Why not just `templates\account\login.html`?

Comment: 'main' is the name of the app I am using

Comment: remove the extra `main`

Comment: `ProjectName\main\templates\account\login.html` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try to move account dir up 1 level, and create *templates* dir at project level, not *main* app level. like this:

```
ProjectName\templates\account\login.html
```